# URL redirection not working with index.php

Tags: nginx

I have this URL

```
https://example.org/index.php/foobar.html
```

That I want to redirect to

```
https://example.org/xpto/foobar/
```

I tried this

```
rewrite ^/index.php/foobar.html /xpto/foobar/ permanent;
```

But no luck. What can be?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($request_filename ~ /foobar.html) {
  rewrite ^ https://example.org/xpto/foobar/ permanent;
}
```